# How to use multiple Identity server inside microservices application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Is it possible to work with two different Identity server inside you microservices application?

I have 2 client applications, 2 BFF gateway, multiple API-s and 2 existing Identity servers.
each client application should be directed to different identity servers.

Would it be possible with custom middleware, by checking witch client application requesting and activate corresponding identity server middleware.

Answer (score 1):

In the client application, you can have multiple AddOpenIDConnect, that point to different IdentityServers. You need to choose which one should do the challenge of the user during sign-in.

For AddJwtBearer, I think it should be fine, also to have multiple instances, one for each IdentityServer instance (to get the public signing keys...). You might need to add some custom event handling, to make sure that the first JwtBearer handler forwards the request to the second one, in case the token is not accepted.

For the API, you can use the Audience claim to ensure that the APIs only accept tokens from the desired IdentityServer.